# Error with context.scriptLoader in next js 10

Tags: next.js

I'm getting this error when running my NextJS app

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'eager' of undefined
    at Head.getPreloadMainLinks (/Users/someuser/dev/temp/next-js-10-1-error/mobile/.next/server/pages/_document.js:4936:30)
    at Head.render (/Users/someuser/dev/temp/next-js-10-1-error/mobile/.next/server/pages/_document.js:5160:130)
```

My app was working fine in next js 10.0.1 but does not work on 10.1.3

I created an MVE here: https://github.com/jeznag/next-js-10-1-error

I'm not sure it is a bug in next as even if I revert to 10.0.1 in the MVE, I still get the error. (But in my real app on 10.0.1 I don't get an error)

Comment: Might be somehow connected that you have shared folder with different nextjs version?